# JQuery Tabs Ajax not working on IE7 when loading same page with different parameters

Tags: jquery, tabs

I am trying to implement jquery ui tabs in ajax mode as shown in http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax. Only difference is , all my tabs urls load the same page with different parameters. This works perfectly fine on Firefox but it is not working on IE7. Can somebody help fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Here is my code.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="tabs.aspx.cs" Inherits="Files_tabs" %>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $("#tabs").tabs({
            ajaxOptions: {
                error: function (xhr, status, index, anchor) {
                    $(anchor.hash).html(
                    "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. ");
                }
            }
        });


    });
</script>
```

```
   <asp:Panel ID="pnlMain" runat="server" >
       <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabs-1">Preloaded</a></li>
                <li><a href="tabs.aspx?id=1" >Panel 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="tabs.aspx?id=2">Panel 2</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tabs-1">
                <p>Testing JQuery AJAX Tabs.</p>
            </div>

      </div>
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel ID="pnlTest1" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <p>Hi this is Test 1.</p>
</asp:Panel>

 <asp:Panel ID="pnlTest2" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <p>Hi this is Test 2.</p>
</asp:Panel>


</form>
```

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string id = "";

    if (Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
    {
        id = Request.QueryString["id"];
    }

    switch (id)
    {
        case "1": pnlMain.Visible = false; pnlTest1.Visible = true; break;
        case "2": pnlMain.Visible = false; pnlTest2.Visible = true; break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured out what the issue is. As I am loading the same page in the tab, the script on the page is duplicated which is messing up the page. I changed the script as shown below to fix this issue.

This generates tabs only when main tab panel is rendered on the page and all other panels (div) are null/hidden. In this case the tabs are generated only the first time main page loads, and when we load the same page in the tab but to show different content of the page, it wont generate the script for tabs.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () 
    {
        if ($("#pnlTest1").html() == null && $("#pnlTest2").html() == null)
        {
            $("#tabs").tabs({
                cache: false,
                ajaxOptions: {
                    cache: false,
                    error: function (xhr, status, index, anchor) {
                        $(anchor.hash).html("Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. ");
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    });

</script>
```